# Send URL attachment with PHP mail() function

Tags: php

I am sending attachments by uploading through `<input type="file" />` but now I want to know if we can send attachments just using `URL` of a file?

Like if I add `<input type="url" name="file[]" />` and I need to send this as attachment not in body as inline link in message.

For now I am using this code:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="code.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiiple" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    foreach(array_combine($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']) as $tmp_name => $file_name ) {
        $filetmp[] = $tmp_name;
        $filename[] = $file_name;
    }

    // email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
    $to = "receiver_email";
    $from = "sender_email"; 
    $subject ="My subject"; 
    $message = "My message";
    $headers = "From: $from";

    // boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    // headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

    // multipart boundary 
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    // preparing attachments
    for($x=0;$x<count($filetmp);$x++){
        $file = fopen($filetmp[$x],"rb");
        $data = fread($file,filesize($filetmp[$x]));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$filename[$x]\"\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$filename[$x]\"\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Sure, use a `<imput type="text"/>` and validate it serverside

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send attachments with PHP Mail()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail)

Comment: You need to add file in some folder to send URL in email

Comment: @AmitGupta yes I have a folder on server in which I have files and I will get url from that folder.

Comment: Yes then simply you need to add image url in your HTML email.

Comment: @AmitGupta but that will be as inline message attachment but I need it to be as file attachment outside of the body. Can you suggest a snippet by grounding my code I mention above?

Comment: You can either attach image with your email or send link of it in the email message itself. I used to do the 2nd option all the time.

Comment: I know that I can send links instead of attachments but I am trying to send attachments. Can you edit my code if you are able to?